# Unit Testing Typescript/React that has Imported SVGs with Jasmine

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm using Jasmine to write unit tests for a Typescript/React project. I'm having trouble because in one of the TSX files, I import an SVG. I am running my unit tests with the command `ts-node node_modules/.bin/jasmine` and when ts-node goes to transpile the .ts files, it fails on the error `Cannot find module './demo.svg'.`

I'm fairly sure that if I build my project (I'm using webpack) then I could run tests against that build, but I'd rather run against the original source if possible, and write my tests in typescript as well. What am I missing? Is there any way to accomplish this?

Here is my sample code:

```
import * as demoImg from './demo.svg'

const demo = {
   generate: (records: ForcedRecord[], groupings: Group[], params:any) => {

   return (
      <div>
         <img src={demoImg}/>
      </div>
   )
}

export default demo
```

Here is my (abridged and trivialized) sample test:

```
import demoCmp from '../../src/processors/demo/demo'

describe('demo', () => {

    let result

    beforeEach(() => {
        result = demoCmp.generate([], [], {})
    })

    it('should return a non-null result', () => {
        expect(result).not.toBeUndefined()
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using a Webpack loader to "import" the SVG file in your Webpack build.  When you run your tests against the source using ts-node, there is no way that import will work unless you use a Node require hook that provides functionality equivalent to that of your Webpack loader; I don't know if such a thing exists.  The easiest option is probably to run the tests against the Webpack bundle, as you mentioned.